# Update page after downloading the file in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I update page after downloading a file in `asp.net core 2`?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportDataAsPDF(BerichteSearch model)
{
   // some codes...
    FileStreamResult resultFile = File(memoryStream.Result, "application/pdf", fileName);
    return resultFile;
}
```

Comment: redirect to another page from that method.Or do you want to show the content of the file?

Comment: It depends on whether you are calling ExportDataAsPDF asynchronously using something like AJAX, or synchronously where you expect a page refresh. If the latter then you can return a view with the same model which includes the resultFile and the rest is Razor/html to display the contents of the model.